# shortest distance between the point $(0,-3)$ and the curve $y=1+a_{1}x^2 + a_{2}x^4 + ....+a_{n}x^{2n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If each $a_{i}>0,$ Then the shortest distance between the point $(0,-3)$ and the curve

$$y=1+a_{1}x^2 + a_{2}x^4 + \cdots +a_{n}x^{2n}$$ is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $P(x,y)$ be ant point on the curve $y=1+a_{1}x^2 + a_{2}x^4 + \cdots +a_{n}x^{2n}$ and

Let $Q(0,-3)$, Then Distance between $PQ = \sqrt{x^2+(y+3)^2}\Rightarrow (PQ)^2 = x^2+(y+3)^2$

Now How can I solve after that

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in terms of $a_i$ or is there a rsetriction on how many of those variables you can use?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem if you plot the curve. It is something like a parabola whose vertex is at $(0,1)$. From this it's easy to see that the shortest distance is 4.

To solve this analytically, note that
$$
1\leq1+a_1x^2+\cdots a_nx^{2n}=y(x),\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}
$$
And $y(0)=1$. So
$$
4\leq y(x)+3
$$
Therefore,
$$
16\leq (y(x)+3)^2+x^2= (P_xQ)^2
$$
Where $P_x=(x, y(x))$. Since $16=(P_0Q)^2$, the minimum is 4.

Comment: I did not understand how you got this step: $16\leq(y(x))^2+x^2$@Brandon

Comment: @Brahmagupta There was a mistake in the post. I already fixed it. Thanks for pointing out that.